# SQL-native method of finding 500 largest items per user in a list of files? (without resorting to coding a for-each loop)

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an SQL table of items that looks something like this:

```
| item_id | company_id | size | user_id |
|---------|------------|------|---------|
| 124521  | 5123       | 200  | 3426    |
| 343526  | 5123       | 6000 | 6334    |
| 803032  | 3443       | 10   | 9585    |
```

Each item has a unique `item_id`, and also an associated `company_id` and `user_id` (Companies and users are stored in a separate table).

I'd like to find the largest 500 items by size (based on the `size` column) for each user present in the table.

If I just do a normal `LIMIT` - I can only limit to say, the top 500 items for a specific user. But I don't know how to do it for **each** user.

Is there a way to do this in SQL only? (The hacky workaround I'm thinking is to lookup a list of all users, and do a for-each, with a separate SQL query for each user - but I'd rather find a SQL-native way to do it if possible.)

Whatever way you come up, ideally I can then JOIN it against the company and user's table, to lookup their human-readable names.

Comment: tag the dbms you are using. also explain what `largest 500 items` means.

Comment: You'd use `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` for this. This is standard SQL and should be supported by most DBMS. MySQL is a known exception to this, though. What is your DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using window functions.

```
select *
from (
  select item_id, company_id, size, user_id, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by size desc) as rnk
  from items)
) t
where rn <= 500
order by user_id, size desc;
```

This assumes "largest" means "the one with the greatest `size`"

Comment: I think `row_number()` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Using joins, I joined the same table, and used grouped by, limit and order by. The table I just called it item_table. I assumed by first 500 you mean top largest numbers of item_id.

```
SELECT x.item_id, x.company_id, x.size, x.user_id
   FROM item_table x  -- lets call it item_table
   JOIN (SELECT y.item_id, y.user_id,
             ORDER BY y.item_id DESC
             LIMIT(500)
        FROM item_table y
    GROUP BY y.user_id) z ON x.user_id = z.user_id
```

Comment: Aha, sorry, I edited the question to clarify I meant largest 500 by size (as in, the "size" column).